# SSLStrip still HTTPS

Tags: encryption, tls, web-browser, man-in-the-middle, sslstrip

I did all the configuration right. IPtables, port forwarding, ARPspoof, everything.
However, in the browser websites like Facebook and Twitter are still HTTPS.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Pick a softer target.

- [Facebook is on the Chromium HSTS preload list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json#1401)
- [Twitter is on the Chromium HSTS preload list](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json#589)

## Update 1

So:
Pick a target that doesn't use HSTS and/or [pick a browser that doesn't care about HSTS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=stricttransportsecurity).

Comment: I don't want to hack someone. i want to learn. how can i bypass this HSTS?

Comment: @Antonio: HSTS is intended as protection against sslstrip etc, so no bypass of HSTS with sslstip, especially not HSTS preload.

Comment: @SteffenUllrichs Oh .. alright. so all the websites here https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/net/+/master/http/transport_security_state_static.json#1401 will not be http ever ? 

And there is a way to bypass HSTS? not with SSLSTRIP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich what about mitmf?

Comment: @Antonio: MITM works only if the CA is already trusted by the browser. If HSTS is used the certificate warnings does not allow override by the user.

Comment: @Antonio: Answer updated.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff I even tried internet explorer. doesn't work on facebook/Twitter .

Comment: IE11 and IE-Edge [both use the Preload lists](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/09/http-strict-transport-security-comes-to-internet-explorer-11-on-windows-8-1-and-windows-7/).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Worked for me just a couple of weeks ago, maybe I used was using a different tool or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's worked for me in the past. If I recall correctly; you may need to de-authenticate your victim and wait for them to re-connect. On account of EAP/EAPOL, I do believe.